# Erro ao executar run-android num projeto react native

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

Eu estou tentando executar o comando "react-native run-android" em projeto que foi passado para mim e não está funcionando.

Já tentei alterar o arquivo gradle.properties para usar o AndroidX mas só dá outro erro, também já tentei alterar o arquivo de manifest como o erro sugere mas também não funciona.

[image: console com o erro]

```
> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED
/home/leleuvilela/Workspace/waproject-base-app/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
        Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactopport-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreCompo
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run wi

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 5s
132 actionable tasks: 122 executed, 10 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Já baixei um container do docker só para rodar esse projeto e também não funcionou, então acho que não deve ser minha máquina.

Answer (score 0):

Olha isso aqui não é bem uma resposta e depois de um tempo eu vou tirar, é só para tentar te ajudar de alguma forma....

Veja bem, quando acontece comigo erros deste tipo com compiladores e executores e que no qual não consigo resolver, como uma última tentativa eu crio um novo projeto, executo para ver se está tudo bem e depois eu passo todas as classes e implementações. Se der certo, eu continuo no novo projeto e abandono o antigo....

Eu não tenho ponto nesta conta para poder comentar então escrevi minha sugestão como resposta mesmo.... (Obs! vou tirar pois é só para você ver mesmo)